# Sumar cantidad de articulo agrupados por subdeposito

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy utilizando Laravel para un proyecto, y ahora necesito poder obtener de una tabla `log_movements` un listado de articulos por `subdeposito`.
En la tabla tengo una columna `quantity` que define la cantidad de elementos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo lo que hago ahora es obtener todos los `log_movements` agrupados por `log_article_id` pasando un `log_sub_deposit_id` como muesntro en el siguente metodo del `Controller`

```
public function articlesBySubdeposit($log_sub_deposit_id)
    {
        $movements = Movement::where('log_sub_deposit_id', $log_sub_deposit_id)
                ->groupBy('log_article_id')
                ->get();
                
        return new MovementCollection($movements);
    }
```

Con el codigo anterior obtengo registros con esta estructura:

```
{
            "id": 319,
            "quantity": 7,
            "description": 0,
            "article": "Casandra",
            "total_article": "",
            "subDeposit": "Suite 969",
            "user": "administrador",
            "provision": 2,
            "type": "Alta de stock",
            "created_at": "11/08/2020"
        },
```

Esta es una posible solucion que brindaron en esta pregunta

```
$movements = Movement::selectRaw('log_article_id, SUM(quantity) as Total')
                ->where('log_sub_deposit_id', $log_sub_deposit_id)
                ->groupBy('log_article_id')
                ->get();
```

Pero este codigo me devuelve lo siguente:

```
{
   "log_article_id": 8,
    "Total": 7
}
```

No respeta el formato que necesito,

Filtro por `log_sub_deposit_id` y luego lo agrupo por `log_article_id`

Yo ahora necesito poder tener una columna extra en el cual me muestre la sumatoria de la columna `quantity` de cada articulo agrupado, pero que solamente sume los `quantitys` que tengan el `log_sub_deposit_id` igual a `$log_sub_deposit_id`

Espero haberme expresado bien.

---

(solcionado)
Edit - Segunda consulta Relacionada :

Una ultima consulta, si yo quiero agregar otro where, por ejemplo:

`where('log_movement_type', 1)`

Dejando la query de la siguente manera:

```
$movements = Movement::selectRaw('SUM(quantity) as Total')
            ->select('log_article_id,', 'columna2', 'columna3', 'columnaN')
            ->where('log_sub_deposit_id', $log_sub_deposit_id)->where('log_movement_type', 1)
            ->groupBy('log_article_id', 'columna2', 'columna3', 'columnaN')
            ->get();
```

Va retornar la sumaria de los articulos en el cual cumplen con la condicion dada cierto?

Comment: Yo la busqueda la estoy iniciando con un `log_sub_deposit_id` luego agrupo por `log_article_id`, y quiero que solamente sume los quantitys de los registron que cumplan con `log_sub_deposit_id`

Comment: Para futuras preguntas, es recomendable que pongas un ejemplo de cómo deseas obtener los resultados de tu consulta.

Comment: Muchas gracia. Me ayudaste mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La consulta esta practicamente hecha, lo único que necesitas es:

- Una función de agregación, en este caso `SUM` para sumar los valores de la columna `quantity`
- Puedes en el `SELECT` indicar que columnas tomarás para que de este modo esa(s) misma(s) columna(s) sean las que tomes para el agrupamiento:

Código:

```
$movements = Movement::selectRaw('log_article_id, SUM(quantity) as Total')
                ->where('log_sub_deposit_id', $log_sub_deposit_id)
                ->groupBy('log_article_id')
                ->get();
```

**Edición**

Toma en consideración lo sigueinte:

- Si necesitas que en tu resultado aparezcan los valores de mas columnas entonces debes incluirlos en tu `SELECT`
- Por todas las columnas que pongas en tu `SELECT` y que NO sean producto de funciones de agregación, deberás agregarlas en el `GROUP BY`
- Para que la agrupación funcione y renglones iguales se fusionen entonces deberán poseer valores idénticos, **en caso de que existan renglones con similitudes pero algunas columnas diferentes, entonces el agrupamiento en esas no funcionará y deberás elegir otro método tal vez `GROUP CONCAT`**

Tu nueva consulta debe tener esta estructura:

```
$movements = Movement::selectRaw('SUM(quantity) as Total')
            ->select('log_article_id,', 'columna2', 'columna3', 'columnaN')
            ->where('log_sub_deposit_id', $log_sub_deposit_id)
            ->groupBy('log_article_id', 'columna2', 'columna3', 'columnaN')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Parece que funciona, pero no es lo que quiero, porque ahora perdi la realciones de eloquent.
Tengo definino practicamente por cada `log_*_id` de la tabla `log_movements` un `belongsTo`.

Comment: Esa consulta me duvuelve lo siguente
```
"log_article_id" => 8
"total_article" => "7"
 ```
cuando en realidad necesito de todos los datos practicamente

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta, me parece que no fui claro, ahi muetro como lo obtengo en ambos casos.

Comment: Claro eso quiero, porque yo en el frontend neceito esos indices para llamar a los datos.

Comment: Perfecto. Es lo que quiero. Ahi agregue una seunda consulta relacionada con el tema, mas que nada para sacerme la duda.